# aws s3 paperclip and rails 3.0 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

First off thanks so much for taking the time to read my question. Thank you! It appears that i'm having trouble implementing aws s3 on my webapp. I have a ROR app deployed o heroku and I'd like to allow users to upload a profile picture to their profile.

I've installed imagemagick and paperclip to handle the attachments. Then someone informed me that heroku does not accept uploads and that I'll need to subscribe to aws-s3. That made sense. So I signed up for aws and added the following code to my project:

user.rb (model)

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => {:small => "70x70>"},
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

s3.yml (file is located in config folder) note: all of these buckets exist on my aws-s3

```
development:
  bucket: my_avatar-dev
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
test:
  bucket: myapp_avatar-test
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
production:
  bucket: myapp_avatar-pro
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
```

gemfile

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

**When I run the application in the development environment (localhost) everything functions properly... I checked AWS and my uploads appear there; however, when I deploy my app to heroku it breaks. To elaborate, the app loads the sign-in screen but as soon as a user signs in, the application breaks and redirects to the error 500 page: "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."**

When I hide the following code (and replace :path with some other value) and re-deploy... the app loads, but obviously it lacks the functionality it needs to redirect to aws-s3.

```
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
:path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

As I mentioned, I'm pretty new to rails... so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Was I supposed to link s3.yml somewhere else, a route or something? Maybe it's something that I need to do while deploying? I'd like to thank anyone who can help me, and I am thankful for your time!

Comment: When you look at your production log, what are the specifics of the 500 error?

Comment: ok... ran the logs. it appears the error resides in the following area: AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey (You did not provide both required access keys. Please provide the access_key_id and the secret_access_key.):   I checked my s3.yml file, and it's got both of those keys in there. I even checked the aws site to see if i copied them incorrectly, but they are correct... not sure what's going on.